# Forcing vimdiff to wrap lines?

Tags: vim, word-wrap, vimdiff

When diffing 2 files in VIM, I prefer the lines to be wrapped.  However, vimdiff sets wrap to off by default.

Is there a way to set line wrap automatically for every diff?

Comment: Thanks for your input. It works but only when vim is started in diff mode.  I'm also interested in forcing line wrap when a diff is started from inside vim.  Is it also possible from a similar command?  Thanks!

Comment: It's interesting but I've exactly the opposite problem, but 'set nowrap' doesn't work. Lines are wrapped automatically if I enter the diff mode.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I use the following:

```
autocmd FilterWritePre * if &diff | setlocal wrap< | endif
```

`FilterWritePre` is triggered immediately before a generated diff is written to the buffer, and `setlocal wrap<` copies the global value of `wrap`. Of course it's also possible to simply force `setlocal wrap`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for.  I would vote up, but I can't (too new)...

Comment: I dont know why, but this doesnt work. I am using vim 7 on debian machine. user2442259 Answer works, though.

Comment: @eddy147 Is your global setting `wrap` or `nowrap`? If the latter, try the same `autocmd` with `setlocal wrap` instead of `setlocal wrap<`.

Answer (score 47):

You can put the following in your vimrc.

```
au VimEnter * if &diff | execute 'windo set wrap' | endif
```

Comment: Actually, this works for me and somhow not the one which is accepted answer.

Answer (score 23):

When vim is already started, the commands to start a diff and a wrap are, on each of the split window files:

```
:diffthis
:set wrap
```

However, the diff+wrap is improperly displayed:

If you have a long line on one file, and a short or missing line on the other, then the long line will occupy, say, 2 lines on the first side, by the short or missing line will only occupy 1 line on the second side.

This results in a **vertical shift of the 2 files**. Sure, the colors help to visually compensate this shift. But over several lines of diff, the shift may be higher than the height of the window, making diff unreadable.

*So the question is not fully solved...
Please advise.*

Comment: `:windo set wrap` sets wrap in both splits.

Comment: @SophiaFeng That's not the issue we're talking about here. Every occurrence that the current line from the 2 files occupy different numbers of virtual lines for display, makes the scrollbind more out of sync.

Answer (score 7):

You can run this

```
vimdiff -c 'set wrap' -c 'wincmd w' -c 'set wrap' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to solve this question for a demo where I wanted `vimdiff` to wrap *only* when launched from a certain terminal.

I finally resorted on the crude:

```
alias vimdiff='vimdiff +"windo set wrap"'
vimdiff file.orig file
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have more files, and you don't want to make this permanent in your vimrc

```
vimdiff -c 'windo set wrap' file1 file2 file3 [file4]
```

or just `windo set wrap` once vim is open

Answer (score 1):

Starting from VIM 8.2.2490 there is a `followwrap` option for [`diffopt`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27diffopt%27). You can set it with `:set diffopt+=followwrap`.

Comment: For *Neovim* this is `vim.opt.diffopt:append('followwrap')`.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the `:set diffopt+=followwrap` setting only affects the second pane, for reasons unknown to me.  I have to `:setlocal wrap` separately to get the first pane to also wrap, and that setting only operates if the `diffopt` setting is also in play.  Bizarre, but at least it works.  The trick now will be to put that inside some conditional that checks the vim version, so I can have one `.vimrc` that works across platforms.